# Cardview layout with Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-cardview

I am trying to create a settings menu using cards as the base for each preference category. I have tried to inflate a layout that has CardView as its root, under the PreferenceScreen fragment. This does not work.

Can anyone help me with how I can go about achieving the above?

Thanks

Comment: Have u implemented cardview preference?

Comment: Can u share your examples how you implement it?